# Excel Maxro to edit email category

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am looking for a macro to run in excel that adds a category to an email that is currently open in outlook.

I am not looking for a macro to run inside Outlook, It needs to run in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error / null checking omitted:

```
set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OlApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Categories = "test"
```

Comment: I cannot make this work as I get a "Object variable not set" error. could you help me creating the whole macro in excel to execute this?

Comment: On which line? Is Outlook running at the time? Is a message opened in a separate inspector?

Comment: Hello, outlook is running at the same time, I get the same error whether I have an email on my preview pane or open separate.
The code I implemented: `code` Sub AddCategory()

'Dim OlApp As Object

Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OlApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Categories = "test"



End Sub `code`

Comment: Never mind. I tried to replace your section "test" with Range("P19"), which I had to replace with `code` Dim refCat As String ' define your reference


refCat = Range("P19") `code` thank you for helping